# Selected Rows in DataGridView always 0

Tags: c#, datagridview

i wanted to show the message "You have not selected any rows" if the selected rows is 0.

But, even i click the first row in datagridview, and i trace it, the selected rows always gave me 0.

Why is it like that?

Here is the code:

```
MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count.ToString()); // below function always run, because the selected rows always 0, even i clicked the first row in datagridview (when run the program)

if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 0)
{
    if (choice.comboBox1.Text == "English")
    {
        System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
        sound.Play();
        MessageBox.Show("You Have Not Selected Any Rows!", "Error");
    }
}

else
{
    DeleteDatabase(sender, e);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MSDN says

> The SelectionMode property must be set to FullRowSelect or
>   RowHeaderSelect for the SelectedRows property to be populated with
>   selected rows.

You need to set this property accordingly otherwise no SelectedRows.

Comment: Thanks steve! Solved now. But, the accept button in this forum will be active 8 more minutes, i am sorry if i not accepted your answer yet